# : Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of abstract class

Tags: hibernate, objectmapper, hibernate-types

I've a problem that I've been working to fix it approximately 2 days but still I didn't find any solve about that problem.

I've one concrete and two implemented class which are **FilteredObjectData**, **CustomerFilteredObjectJson** and **ProductFilteredObjectJson**.

The classes are below:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CustomerFilteredObjectJson.class, name = "Customer"),

        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ProductFilteredObjectJson.class, name = "Product")}
)
public abstract class FilteredObjectData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8746510068813833450L;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerFilteredObjectJson extends FilteredObjectData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5827825016371137372L;
    private List<Long> cities;
    private List<Long> distiricts;
    private List<Long> channels;
    private String salesmanCode;
    private List<String> accountCodes;
    private List<String> taxNumbers;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductFilteredObjectJson extends FilteredObjectData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2310254379556207058L;
    private List<String> productCodes;
}
```

At the same time I'm using @vladmihalcea's hibernate-type-52 framework.

Now, when I'm trying to get data from PostgreSQL, I'm getting an error like below;

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class io.salesart.core.entities.json.FilteredObjectData]: missing type id property 'type'
 at [Source: (String)"{"productCodes": []}"; line: 1, column: 20]
```

What are causes that problem? Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a replicating test case based on one of the existing tests found in the [Hibernate Types GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types), then I could take a look to see what the problem is.

Send me a Pull Request with the replicating test case and I'll investigate it afterward.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad for your concern, I've resolved this issue after I've wrote it in here. The problem was related my model, I've changed it and worked what I've expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when I using Optional class.

e.g `Optional<Computer> computer = new Computer();`
and storing `this.saveTo(computer)` directly into cache.

But when I change method arugment as `this.saveTo(computer.get());`
then issue solved.